# eMMC writes randomly takes longer time

Tags: linux-kernel, storage, flash-memory

I'm analysing how long time it takes to write 1 MB to a eMMC. It is supposed to happen during powerfail, thus time is critical.

I found that the write can be done in 40 ms, which is fine.
However randomly (one out of several hundreds) it takes more than 200 ms, which is bad.

Why does these long write times happen. Is it Linux, or is it the eMMC which is doing some housekeeping. I suspect the eMMC, but I have not been able to find any articles about this. Any references would be appreciated.

I run this test script in my init script before anything else is launched, thus the script is alone with all the resources

```sh
dd bs=4096 count=128 if=/dev/zero of=/tmp/e2
t=0
count=0
while [ $t -lt 20 ]
do
t=$(time dd if=/tmp/e2 of=/rootfs/data/test-nvram bs=4M 2>&1)
t=$(echo $t | awk /real/'{print $9}' | tr -d 's.' )
echo $count $t
count=`expr $count + 1`
done
```

I have also tried to write directly to */dev/mmcblk0p1* with the same result, thus the file system does not seem to matter. Doing a lttng on a full system seems to indicate, that the CPU is waiting for an interrupt from the eMMC.

My setup is:
ARMv7 LS1021A dual core, 1GHz
Linux kernel 4.14.34
eMMC: Micron MTFC8GAKAJCN-4M IT

Comment: What does the datasheet say for worst case programming time?

Comment: The datasheet says absolutely nothing. Just an average of 40 ms.